# building backbone collection for array

Tags: arrays, backbone.js, coffeescript

I don't know how to change array into collection.
here is what I want to do (coffeeScript)

```
myArray = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7']
@filters = new Backbone.Collection(myArray)
```

what I am getting is
Backbone.Collection {length: 9, models: Array[7]...}

but each model inside the collection looks weird:

```
attributes:
     Object 0: "s"
            1: "t"
            2: "r"
            3: "1"
```

how can i construct collection so as i have attribute { name : str1 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Backbone Models expect an object not a string. Convert the array to a set of objects:

```
myArray = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7']
myModels = for name in myArray then {name}
@filters = new Backbone.Collection(myModels)
```

Comment: interesting, but your code is producing collection with one model name: str7 how can i get them all?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to give an explanation as to what is happening here,

```
myArray = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 'str6', 'str7']
```

this part takes in your array and stores it within myArray

```
myModels = for name in myArray then {name}
```

the above line of code creates a for loop that loops through the Array. It loops through the array a total number of times equal to myArray.length

```
@filters = new Backbone.Collection(myModels)
```

The above line of code creates a new backbone collection that is based off of the for loop, i.e it then loops through the for loop and stores the result in a collection.